# MS SQL Server 2005: What Happens If LDF-file are lost?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

If I put my MS SQL Log file on another drive and the drive crashes.

What happens to my MS SQL Database, will it create a new log file or how do I correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to recover/repair the database, see here: [Recover a database without the ldf file](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/recover-a-database-without-the-ldf-file)